# How to set-up Memcached for Django?

Tags: django, memcached

I am trying to set-up Memcached solution, but it does not seem to work. I tested caching a view only and whole solution with the same result. Here are my settings.py:

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # CORS
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    # adding caches around CommonMiddleware
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',     # NEW
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',  # NEW

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

# cache settings
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = '6000'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
```

I have installed memcached with Homebrew and is properly running. I have tested it using telnet.

I am trying a call that returns a few thousand results, and I see no time gains for the 2nd call and on. Any help on how to figure this out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you are testing this? Are you trying to cache your **view**/response or cache a database query?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = '6000' passing a string when you should actually pass an int or float , try changing it to CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 6000